# Greek nu (Tex) in matplotlib legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex, legend

I'm plotting with matplotlib.pyplot and I am trying to use the Tex \nu letter in a plot label.
However, with `label='$B_\nu(\nu, T)$'`, I get linebreak+u in the plot legend, since \n is interpreted as a new line. I also tried `label='$B_{\nu}({\nu}, T)$'`, which give the same result plus {} in the output. How can I get nu to work in the legend?

Comment: Escape the backslash -> change \ to \\

Comment: making it a raw string by will also work (the r in front of the string) `label=r'$B_\nu(\nu, T)$`

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
label='$B_\\nu(\\nu, T)$'
```

Comment: Add description what did you changed/modified. Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes